# Getting millisecond format

Tags: java, android, string, format, milliseconds

I am trying to get this string to return Minute:Second:Millisecond for my MediaPlayer. I have found this code, but can't figure out how to make the Milliseconds work and put it at 2 decimal places. I'm sure its simple to the right person!

```
private String getTimeString(long millis) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        int hours = (int) (millis / (1000*60*60));
        int minutes = (int) (( millis % (1000*60*60) ) / (1000*60));
        int seconds = (int) (( ( millis % (1000*60*60) ) % (1000*60) ) / 1000);


        buf
            .append(String.format("%02d", hours))
            .append(":")
            .append(String.format("%02d", minutes))
            .append(":")
            .append(String.format("%02d", seconds));


        return buf.toString();
    }
```

Thanks always guys

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 1000 milliseconds in one second, i.e. you'd need 3 decimal places for the milliseconds:

```
/** return time in format 1:23.456 */
private String getTimeString(long millis) {
    int minutes = (int) (millis / (1000 * 60));
    int seconds = (int) ((millis / 1000) % 60);
    int milliseconds = (int) (millis % 1000);
    String.format("%d:%02d.%03d", minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
}
```

If you absolutely want 2 digits for milliseconds, you actually get 1/100 seconds and not milliseconds:

```
/** return time in format 1:23.45 */
private String getTimeString(long millis) {
    int minutes = (int) (millis / (1000 * 60));
    int seconds = (int) ((millis / 1000) % 60);
    int seconds100 = (int) ((millis / 10) % 100);
    String.format("%d:%02d.%02d", minutes, seconds, seconds100);
}
```

However, a common display format for media players is to use one digit for 10ths of seconds:

```
/** return time in format 1:23.4 */
private String getTimeString(long millis) {
    int minutes = (int) (millis / (1000 * 60));
    int seconds = (int) ((millis / 1000) % 60);
    int seconds10 = (int) ((millis / 100) % 10);
    String.format("%d:%02d.%d", minutes, seconds, seconds10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put the milliseconds at two decimal places, keep in mind that you will only be able to show increments of 10ms; 1ms = 0.001s, three decimal places.  But regardless, the code you are looking for is:

```
int rem_milliseconds = (int)(millis % 1000); // Remaining ms after last second
...
.append(String.format("%02d", rem_milliseconds));
```

I left it at 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private String getTimeString(long millis) {
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis);
    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
                   TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis));
    millis -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes) + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds);

    return String.format("%d:%d:%d", minutes, seconds, millis);
}
```