# How to format Milliseconds

Tags: java, milliseconds

In my code I'm getting milliseconds using

```
// elaspsed time in milliseconds
    public long getElapsedTime() {
        if (running) {
            return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        }
        return stopTime - startTime;
    }
```

As long is a whole number Where as I want to get the milliseconds in **00.0000** format 
However I've tried this so far

```
return ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000f);
```

but I am not getting to particular format

Comment: What do you mean "milliseconds in 00.0000 format"? Can you show an example of expected output?

Comment: @Tunaki like the part before decimal for seconds and after decimal part the rest of milliseconds

Comment: You and `String.format()` will be new best friends!
http://stackoverflow.com/a/50544/1429387

Comment: A much more specific duplicate is the poorly-titled "[Getting millisecond format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049009)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for you to set the return type to long and return a `double` or `String` value.

However if you need to format a millisecond value to the provided format, you should be able to get it done using following code snippet.

```
String.format("%d.%d",  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millies),millies%1000);
```